# Visualization of metric on a specified grid in R-Caret

Tags: r, r-caret

When running train function for SVM and specifying a grid:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 50, verboseIter = TRUE,
                       savePredictions = TRUE, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = MySummary)
  SVMgrid <- expand.grid(sigma = seq(0.0025,0.03,0.0025), C = seq(0.5,20,2))
  mod_fit <- train(Thrombosis ~ .,  data=df, method="svmRadial", trControl=ctrl,
                   tuneGrid=SVMgrid, preProc=c("scale","YeoJohnson"), metric="Kappa",
                   allowParallel = TRUE)
```

An output is an object that has the value of a desired metric across a specified grid:

```
> res$model$results
    sigma    C  Accuracy     Kappa
    1   0.0025  0.5 0.9133391 0.1749249
    2   0.0025  2.5 0.9138762 0.2059130
    3   0.0025  4.5 0.9183870 0.2710625
    4   0.0025  6.5 0.9194742 0.2730091
    5   0.0025  8.5 0.9198104 0.2733598
    6   0.0025 10.5 0.9204425 0.2787055
    7   0.0025 12.5 0.9210958 0.2811878
    8   0.0025 14.5 0.9217887 0.2869429
    9   0.0025 16.5 0.9224985 0.2897108
    10  0.0025 18.5 0.9222014 0.2837258
    11  0.0050  0.5 0.9154192 0.2231682
```

How can one visualize that as a grid of squares, or in another appropriate way?

Comment: I'd look into using the `persp` plotting function, but if you want code, you should bring data. You are not the Almighty that  Deming was referring to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't get the reference.

I am not sure what additional code, is required, as I thought that these caret train objects have standard format independent of the previous code. I edited the question to give the commands that produced it.

Comment: Google: "In God we trust, all others must bring data" You don't offer enough data to construct a sample.